# How to get object metadata like recordtypes entirely clientside in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, metadata, record-type

I am working on a Lightning Component and want to create a record using `lightning:recordEditForm`. using `lightning:recordEditForm` is great because it allows us to create records without Apex.

However, I need to pass a RecordTypeId to that component and that's where I get stuck. I would like to find the proper recordTypeId **clientside** so that I don't need an Apex controller that queries the recordTypes and returns them just so I can select the proper Id given a recordType name.

Is it possible to do it entirely clientside?

With the new Lightning Web Components, we have a wire adapter to get Object Info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info

Is there something similar for the 'classic' Lightning Components?
Maybe with the Lightning Data Service?

Answer (score 0):

The hasPageReference interface provides pagereference object and it's property called state includes RecordTypeId.
See the answer below:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227943/61793

Comment: Even with links to SFSE, I think it'd be preferable to reproduce the important bits in this answer.

Comment: If you can put the actual solution in your answer (instead of linking) then I'll be glad to upvote and accept it.